# Spark CSV parsing for different files and options using univocity csv parser scala

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, univocity

I am trying to parse this csv file with the following settings.

```
ArrayType
"[""a"",""ab"",""avc""]"
"[1,23,33]"
"[""1"",""22""]"
"[""1"",""22"",""12222222.32342342314"",123412423523.3414]"
"[a,c,s,a,d,a,q,s]"
"["""","""","""",""""]"
"["","","",""]"
"[""abcgdjasc"",""jachdac"",""''""]"
"[""a"",""ab"",""avc""]"

val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true").option("escape","\"").option("quote","\"").load("/home/ArrayType.csv")
```

Output:

scala> df.show()

```
+--------------------+
|           ArrayType|
+--------------------+
|    ["a","ab","avc"]|
|           [1,23,33]|
|          ["1","22"]|
|["1","22","122222...|
|   [a,c,s,a,d,a,q,s]|
|       ["","","",""]|
|           [",",","]|
|["abcgdjasc","jac...|
|    ["a","ab","avc"]|
+--------------------+
```

However since here the escape character is "\"" , I am able to read it as a single column , whereas, If the input file looks like below ,

```
ArrayType
"["a","ab","avc"]"
"[1,23,33]"
"["1","22"]"
"["1","22","12222222.32342342314",123412423523.3414]"
"[a,c,s,a,d,a,q,s]"
"["","","",""]"
"[",",","]"
"["abcgdjasc","jachdac","''"]"
"["a","ab","avc"]"
```

It shows me the following output , whereas I need it to parse the same way it did before .

scala> df.show()

```
+-----------------+-------+--------------------+-------------------+
|              _c0|    _c1|                 _c2|                _c3|
+-----------------+-------+--------------------+-------------------+
|            "["a"|     ab|             "avc"]"|                   |
|        [1,23,33]|       |                    |                   |
|            "["1"| "22"]"|                    |                   |
|            "["1"|     22|12222222.32342342314|123412423523.3414]"|
|[a,c,s,a,d,a,q,s]|       |                    |                   |
|        [",",","]|       |                    |                   |
|                [|      ,|                   ]|                   |
|    "["abcgdjasc"|jachdac|              "''"]"|                   |
|            "["a"|     ab|             "avc"]"|                   |
|            "["a"|     ab|             "avc"]"|                   |
+------+-------------+-----------------+-------+--------------------
```

So, even if the string is not escaped , I still want to get the same output as the previous , without separated by comma.

How to get the second csv file as a single column in a dataframe ?

How to support both kind of files to be parsed as a single column ?

I am using univocity CSV parser for parsing.